# Why Transform.rotateZ does not rotate my Surface clockwise

Tags: javascript, rotation, transform, famo.us, rotatetransform

I play around with the Famo.us transformations, and I noticed a strange behavior with rotations.

A little explanation is necessary for you to understand what's really going on.

Each time you click the blue button, the red surface rotate 90 degrees.

The first, second and fourth rotations going clockwise. Very well !

But the third rotation, when you go from 180 degrees to 270 degrees, is performed anticlockwise.

Here is my code :

```
define('main', function(require, exports, module) {
    var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
    var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
    var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
    var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');

    var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
    var theta = 0;

    var button = new Surface({
        size:[200, 25],
        content: 'Click me to rotate the red cube',
        properties: { color:'white', backgroundColor:'blue'}
    });

    var cube = new Surface({
        size:[100, 100],
        content: 'I\'m a cube',
        properties: { color:'white', backgroundColor:'red'}
    });

    buttonMod = new StateModifier({ origin: [0, 0] });
    cubeMod = new StateModifier({ origin: [.5, .5] });

    mainContext.add(buttonMod).add(button);
    mainContext.add(cubeMod).add(cube);

    button.on('click', function() {
        rotateClockWise();
    });

    function rotateClockWise() {
        theta += Math.PI / 2;
        cubeMod.setTransform(Transform.rotateZ(theta), {duration: 300});
    }
});
```

For testing purpose I made a little JSFiddle visible here : http://jsfiddle.net/qb1rceLz/

Nevertheless the documentation says :

> **Transform.rotateZ(theta)**
>
> Return a Transform which represents a clockwise rotation around the z axis.

Did I missed something, or do you know any workaround to fix this behaviour ?

**EDIT :**

Here is a JSFiddle with my integration of the Talves solution, hope this could help someone : http://jsfiddle.net/7rbkLrtn/

Comment: I have been experimenting a bit and it seems as the square rotates clockwise if the argument is in the interval `[0, PI]` and counter-clockwise else.

Comment: Not really. To be precise, the rotation is performed clockwise in the interval [0, PI] and in the interval [3PI/2, 2PI]. Did you looked at the JSFiddle that I've provided ? It exactly reproduce what's going on.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. The rotaton should be clockwise. The thing I described was just what I draw as a conclusion from the fiddle. It seems to me something is wrong with the rotation function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not really missing anything.  You may just need an explanation of what is happening.

### Explanation

> **Transform.rotateZ(theta)**
>
> Return a Transform which represents a clockwise rotation around the z axis.

This does not mean it will `transition` clockwise around the z axis.  It means it will represent a vector location starting at 0 measured clockwise in theta radians.  The radians are represented from 0 through 2 * PI.  **Note:** 2 * PI is the same as 360 degrees or 0. If we take (2 * PI) / 360 we get the `theta radians` value for a degree in the circle.

> ```
> cubeMod.setTransform(Transform.rotateZ(theta), {duration: 300});
> ```

The `{duration: 300}` in this line sets a transform state when you call the `setTransform` of the modifier. When you use the transition, there is a **`transition`** from the last state to the new state.  In this case, Famo.us transitions from `rotateZ(theta) theta=PI` to `rotateZ(theta) theta > PI` in a counter-clockwise direction because of it's interpretation of the matrix values returned.  Whether this is a bug or just a short-coming of the method, is up to you to decide.

If you leave it out, you will get the instant setting of the Transform matrix returned from `Transform.rotateZ(theta)` on the modifier.

### Solution

The correct way to move from one radian to another when using rotateZ is dependent on the effect we want.  In this case you want a rotation clockwise to the next rotation radian value.

**[Here is one example of how it can be done.](http://jsbin.com/luxepi/3/edit?javascript,live)**

Comment: Great answer ! Thank you so much for this detailed answer and the code provided. In fact I think I need to dive a little bit more into the differences between `StateModifier` and `Modifier`. The `Modifier.transformFrom()` function does the job, excellent ! But as it's evaluated at each tick of the Engine, I still wonder if it's a good solution in a program where transformations are continuously done. Anyway in my case it's an acceptable solution. Good job my friend.

Comment: No problem.  You are right.  There is a performance consideration when using the `.tranformFrom()` function.